# How to perform a whereIN query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to perform a `whereIN` query in Laravel. The value that I want to match is a value from a database table like: "a,b,c,d"

I want to select all the users who has a name that is contained in this string above.
So I take the string and explode it to create an array and then i add this array to the Laravel command.The problem is that it returns only one user that matches only the letter "a" for example and it stops.

The Controller code:

```
public function returnEorti(){

    $month = Input::get('month');
    $day = Input::get('day');

    $eorti = DB::select("select text from days where day='$day' and month='$month'");
    $eortiFinal = explode(",", $eorti[0]->text);
    $pelatis = Pelatis::whereIn('Onoma', $eortiFinal)->get();

    return json_encode($pelatis);
}
```

The ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"getEorti",
    data:{"day":d[2],"month":d[1]},
    success:function(data){
        var b = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
        for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(b).length;i++){
            $( "#test" ).append( b[i].Onoma+'</br>' );
        }      
        console.log(data);      
    }            
 });
```

And my route:

```
Route::get('getEorti','EortologioController@returnEorti');
```

The 'Pelates' table: 
p_id 
Onoma 
Epitheto
Onoma_Miteras
Onoma_Patera
Hmerominia_Gennisis
Tilefono_Oikias
Kinito_Tilefono
Diefthinsi 
Dimos
Periferia
Periferiaki_Enotita
Epaggelma 
Email

Comment: What are the actual values in `$eortiFinal`, and which `Pelatis` db rows are you expecting to match? This isn't exactly an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Pelatis is the table for customers...$eortiFinal is an array , it has the "a,b,c,d" i've mentioned before but exploded by the ',' delimiter.

Comment: Yes I realize Pelatis is a table, what rows are in the table?

Comment: there is a row called 'Onoma' , i want to compare the string in the $eortiFinal with 'Onoma' to pick the customers i want

Comment: Is `$eorti[0]->text` exactly "a,b,c,d"?

Comment: What do you mean by a row called 'Onoma'? I would expect there to be a column 'Onoma', not a row. Could you include a summary of the data in the Pelatis table in your question, including columns and rows?

Comment: Yes i've made a mistake , its a column .

Comment: You aren't really including enough information to help solve the problem. What is the output from `console.log(data)` in the success function? What rows are in the database table which you think should match?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in `DB` query

`$eorti = DB::select("select text from days where day='$day' and month='$month'");`

Should be corrected as

```
eorti = DB::table('days')->whereDay($day)->whereMonth($month)->get();
```

Comment: No unfortunately it doesnt help... The problem is tha the query returns only users matches the first element in the string and ignores the rest.

Comment: For example : i have two users with names 'Maria' , 'Panagiotis'.When the query starts , it gets the date and it finds the string with the names for that day .... For example the found string is 'Maria,'Panagiotis','Marios' . The user returned is only 'Maria'

Comment: Did you tried returning just `$pelatis` or `$pelatis->toJson()` instead of json_encode($pelatis) ?

Comment: If the answer worked for you, please accept it as answer so that it may help someone else in the future.